# Solving a system of equations with three unknowns with log

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve a system of equations with three unknowns with log like this:
$$\begin{cases}
  x + \log_2 y = 2 \\
  y + \log_2 z = 4 \\
  z + \log_2 x = 2 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Doubt this one has a nice analytical solution. Solving gives the equation $z = 2^{4-2^{2-2^{2-z}}}$ which is not very pleasant. A numerical solution is not hard using for example bisection.

Comment: One can show there cannot be more than one solution, though finding this solution needs numerical methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eliminate $y$ and $z$ with

$$z=2-\log_2(x)\\y=4-\log_2(z)=4-\log_2(2-\log_2(x)).$$

Then

$$x+\log_2(4-\log_2(2-\log_2(x)))=2.$$

From a plot of the function, you clearly see a single root for $x$ in $(0,1)$, near $0.63$.

(More precisely, $0.629899114485807252\cdots$ by numerical resolution)

[image]

---

Uniqueness of the root is established by the monotonicity of the function (inherited from the monotonicity of the logarithm). Existence is proven by

$$f\left(\frac14\right)=\frac54<2,\\
f(2)=4>2.$$